How can I access arguments of a call to a function stored in a custom environment?
I am in the following situation:

I use a custom environment (some_env) that stores a list of functions (such as some_function()). Note that I don’t own this environment, it is imported from another package
I have a user-facing function that calls the function stored in the environment under the hood.

library(rlang)

# Define a custom environment where I store a function.
# This is done in another package.
some_env <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
class(some_env) <- "custom_class"
some_env$some_function <- function(x) {
  print(x)
}

# Make a user-facing function that calls the function stored in the custom
# environment under the hood
user_facing_fn <- function(val = 1) {
  some_env$some_function(val)
}

user_facing_fn()
#> [1] 1

My objective is to capture the call to this internal function (some_function()). I could do this inside user_facing_fn() using rlang::expr() and !!. However, in the real situation, I have many user-facing functions so using this combination would greatly clutter the code.
Therefore, I thought about defining a custom class and $ call so that I can access the call before dispatching it to the next method.
# Define a custom `$` to access the call before evaluating it 
`$.custom_class` <- function(x, name) {
  fc <- rlang::frame_call()
  
  ### For debugging
  cat("----------------\n")
  print(fc)
  cat("----------------\n")
  print(str(fc))
  cat("----------------\n")
  print(deparse(fc))
  ###
  
  NextMethod("$")  # <<<<<<<<<<<<< Not interested in this part
}

It seems that I can capture the call with frame_call() and it is correctly printed (see the first printed line below):
user_facing_fn()
#> ----------------
#> some_env$some_function(val)
#> ----------------
#>  language `$.custom_class`(some_env, "some_function")
#>  - attr(*, "srcref")= 'srcref' int [1:8] 14 3 14 29 3 29 14 14
#>   ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x000001d40b90c0c0> 
#> NULL
#> ----------------
#> [1] "`$.custom_class`(some_env, \"some_function\")"
#> [1] 1

However, I can’t find a way to access the value of val after storing the expression in fc. As you can see, it is deparsed as `$.custom_class`(some_env, "some_function") but I cannot access val. I tried many rlang functions but couldn’t find something that works.
To clarify, what I want is to be able to access the value of val (in the example above, it would be 1) when I’m inside $.custom_class. Is this possible? I’m fine with using either base R or rlang.

Edit following MrFlick's comment:
My objective is that user_facing_fn() returns the output and an attribute containing the call to the internal function, like this:
...

# Make a user-facing function that calls the function stored in the custom
# environment under the hood
user_facing_fn <- function(val = 1) {
  my_expr <- expr(some_env$some_function(!!val))
  out <- eval_bare(my_expr)
  attr(out, "original_query") <- my_expr
  out
}

user_facing_fn(3)
#> [1] 3
#> attr(,"original_query")
#> some_env$some_function(3)

The problem is that I have many user-facing functions, and in some of them I want to capture several calls to functions stored in some_env. Therefore, I thought that instead of duplicating this expr() + !!, I could automatically capture the call in $ and I wouldn't need to modify the user-facing functions (or just slightly).

If you look at the abstract syntax tree for this type of call, for example lobstr::ast(a$b(c)), you'll see the c is not contained in the $ call. The $ is just an extraction operator returning an element from a list usually. It's more like you are calling (a$b)(c). You might be able to walk up the call stack to find it, but then you still have the problem of forcing evaluation of that parameter if it since it's not evaluated yet. Why exactly do you need the value in the $ part? What behavior exactly do you need?

To add to what @MrFlick said, another way of doing this with base R is to stick l <- as.list(match.call()); browser() inside your $.custom_class() function. Then after you call it, in the debug browser, look at l, and you'll see val isn't there. For me it helps to think about the inside of user_facing_function as some_env[["some_function"]](val). You are basically exploring the some_env[["some_function"]] stage, i.e. looking up the function in the environment. This is a comment not an answer because I'm not sure how to do what you are trying to do.

Thanks both, that helps. I added some details at the bottom at the post to clarify why I'd like to access this info from $ and the more general objective

Why not overwrite some_env$some_function? This would be a lot simpler than overwriting the $ operator for the environment to capture the call.

@KonradRudolph I import several environments similar to some_env, and each of them contains dozens or hundreds of functions, so I don't see how I could overwrite all of them. I also don't understand how that would solve the problem or returning the original call as an output attribute, can you clarify?

What about eapply()? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eapply.html

I think I found a way thanks to the various comments.
Setup
I’m just putting back my setting here:
library(rlang)

# Define a custom environment where I store a function.
# This is done in another package.
some_env <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
class(some_env) <- "custom_class"
some_env$some_function <- function(x) {
  x
}

# Make a user-facing function that calls the function stored in the custom
# environment under the hood
user_facing_fn <- function(val = 1) {
  some_env$some_function(val)
}

user_facing_fn(1)
#> [1] 1

Modify the environment
I can modify the functions in some_env so that I can obtain the call and store it somewhere (e.g in an attribute) before evaluating it. First I need eapply() to go through all the functions stored in some_env (in this example, there’s only some_function()):
modify_env <- function(env) {
  
  # Here I overwrite all functions defined in `some_env`. In this example,
  # there's only one.
  
  eapply(env, function(fun) {
    function(...) {
      # Evaluate the args that are passed to the `some_function()`, which is
      # only "val" in this example.
      # First we capture unevaluated args, then we evaluate each of them in the
      # caller env.
      
      fc <- as.list(frame_call())
      # The first element is the call, which is `some_env$some_function()` here.
      # It is not an argument so I remove it.
      fc1 <- fc[[1]]
      fc[[1]] <- NULL
      fc <- lapply(fc, eval_bare, env = caller_env())
      
      # Evaluate the call. This produces the output (which is equal to the 
      # input in this example).
      out <- call2(fun, !!!fc) |> eval_bare()
      
      # Build the call that will be stored in the attributes of the output.
      args <- list2(...)
      full_call <- call2(fc1, !!!fc)
      full_call <- deparse(full_call)
      
      # Store the call in the attribute of the output.
      attr(out, "original_expr") <- full_call
      out
    }
  })
}

Now I define my own environment by cloning some_env and then modify it:
my_new_env <- modify_env(
  env_clone(some_env)
)

Finally, I define a custom $ to access the call to some_env$some_function() before evaluating it. Here, instead of returning some_env$some_function, which would only return the input without storing the call, I return the modified function from the custom environment:
`$.custom_class` <- function(x, name) {
  my_new_env[[name]]
}

We now have the original call stored in the output’s attributes:
user_facing_fn()
#> [1] 1
#> attr(,"original_expr")
#> [1] "some_env$some_function(1)"


user_facing_fn(3)
#> [1] 3
#> attr(,"original_expr")
#> [1] "some_env$some_function(3)"


This is an interesting and clever approach. I think I understand the technical aspect of the problem but not really the wider context. Could you elaborate a little on how you're importing an environment with hundreds of functions that you need to modify? Usually functions come in packages, and most packages don't even have hundreds of functions. I'm trying to work out where to file this away for future use.

The package polars has this kind of structure. Basically, it needs to reimplement a lot of functions (including all the basic arithmetic functions) and there would be tons of conflicts if it just stored them in the package namespace. The solution that was adopted was to store functions in environments, such as RPolarsDataFrame or pl, which gives the package a sort of R6-style (without actually using R6). This is the package that I import in my custom package tidypolars... (1/3)

In tidypolars, I have more "standard" functions that are basically wrappers around functions from polars' various environments (see the code for drop_na() for example). I'm making a function show_query() that shows the raw polars code, and to do that I need to store all the calls to polars functions, hence the origin of this post. (2/3)

If you're interested, I have some WIP in this PR, which deviates from the solution I posted but was originally built on that. (3/3)

Thanks - I've only played around with polars in Python and Rust, partly because of the weird R syntax. I'm kind of surprised that R polars works that way - I'd assumed from the style it was using R6. Had a look at their repo and it looks quite complicated. Your package looks a great way to manage that - not just for the piping but also the names (not quite sure why they called it drop_nulls() as Rust doesn't have null and pandas uses np.nan but drop_na() is obviously a more appropriate name in R). Makes using polars in R a much more attractive option.

Regarding drop_nulls(), it's because missing data is represented by null in the Arrow specification (see this section of polars docs). Agreed that the internals of polars (the R package) are quite different from standard R packages, but it was that or R6 and I assume the original developer also had reasons to avoid R6 (I contribute to polars but I wasn't involved in the original design). The objective is to mimic the Python API as much as possible and then have extensions for alternative syntax (such as tidypolars).
